# Modify child element attributes within an HTML method

Tags: jquery

with JQuery, I am loading HTML into a variable, which then gets loaded into an element via the HTML method - like this...

```
 $(".smabout").html(data_topmenu);
```

The `data_topmenu` variable is loading HTML code.  It looks like this...

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

...but what I want to do is modify the inner HTML attributes of this variable.  I want to remove `id="menu"` from the UL. Is there a way to do that in this current jQuery chain process?

Something like...

```
$(".smabout").html(data_topmenu, function(){
//remove the id attribute on parent UL from this data_topmenu data
});
```

thanks

Comment: have you tried jquery.removeattr()?

Comment: I will have multiple elements that will be adjusted within this data_topmenu variable.  the example above is a simple illustration.  I am eventually going to remove 1 id, 10 classes, and inject new html into curtain areas.

Comment: true, I'm trying to be careful in how I do that, because I am loading this same variable in another place - as my top menu of the site.  But this current process/example, is injecting a sitemap into the middle of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before loading the HTML, you can do a string replacement on your variable, like so:

data_topmenu = data_topmenu.replace(' id="menu"', '');

Comment: thank you my friend.  I didn't know we could do that ahead of time.